# How can I transform values using if statement on map function in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I use **map** function on dataframe rdd  like this :

```
 val df2=df1.select("vScaled")
 val sqldf = df2.rdd
      .map { row => row.getAs[DenseVector]("vScaled").values }
      .map(array => Nd4j.createFromArray(Array(array)))
```

it works but i want to change values in **df2** I mean i want to replace values which below to zero and bigger than 1 to 0 and 1

So how can I change map function to replace **map** function to looking up condition.

I try to use if statement but it fails.

my code :

```
 val sqldf = df2.rdd
    .map {
      row =>
        if (row.getAs[DenseVector]("vScaled").values > double(1) )
        {row.getAs[DenseVector]("vScaled").values = double(1).toArray}
    else if (row.getAs[DenseVector]("vScaled").values< double(0) )
        { row.getAs[DenseVector]("vScaled").values= double(0).toArray }
    else {row.getAs[DenseVector]("vScaled").values}
    }
    .map(array => Nd4j.createFromArray(Array(array)))
```

**code is not valid**

How can i handle that?

thanks in advance

Comment: If you show us your code using `if` we might be able to say what the problem is. (Though it sounds like `math.max` and `math.min` are what you want rather than `if`)

Comment: actually I have no much experience on scala language. most probably I made a misatake on logic. Can you show how to write with math max an min. thanks

Comment: You can limit in the range `0.0` to `1.0` using `math.max(0.0, math.min(1.0, <value>))`. The problem is that `values` is a `DenseVector` not a single value, you need to use a nested `map` to modify all the values in the `DenseVector`. Maybe `.map{ row => row.getAs[DenseVector]("vScaled").values.map(x => math.max(0.0, math.min(1.0, x))) }` (Don't know spark so not posting this as an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Tim

it works with map again with `math.max` and `math.min`

```
 val sqldf = df2.rdd
    .map {
      row => row.getAs[DenseVector]("vScaled").values.map(x => math.max(0.0, math.min(1.0, x)))
    }
    .map(array => Nd4j.createFromArray(Array(array)))
```